# How to add class to tr only when ALL td's has a certain class?

Tags: php, jquery

I've been trying to create a buzzword bingo mainly using PHP. I add a specific class to the keywords from an array of 25 words that are found on a certain website. Now I just want to use jquery to style the row when all cells has that class but I can't figure out how, this is all I've got at the moment.

```
$('td.check').parent('tr').addClass('bingo');
```

PHP:

```
    function bingo() {

$buzzwords = array(
  "kaos",
  "mega",
  "super",
  "kris",
  "tragedi",
  "döds",
  "succé",
  "avslöjar",
  "chocken",
  "terror",
  "attack",
  "mardröm",
  "rekord",
  "galen",
  "knark",
  "attentat",
  "extrem",
  "kollaps",
  "kränkt",
  "skräll",
  "myten",
  "problem",
  "varning",
  "extra",
  "besked"
  );

shuffle($buzzwords);

$inAb = array();


$bingocard = "<table class='tabell'>";
$bingocard .= "<thead><tr>";
$bingocard .= "<th>B</th>
      <th>I</th><th>N</th>
      <th>G</th><th>O</th>";
$bingocard .= "</tr></thead>";
$bingocard .= "<tbody>";
$bingocard .= "<tr>";

for($cell=0; $cell<25; $cell++)
  {

    $rowend = ($cell + 1) % 5;
    $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
        $value = $buzzwords[$cell];
        $antal = substr_count($homepage, $buzzwords[$cell]);
        if ($antal > 0) {
    $bingocard .= "<td class='check' style='color: red;'>" 
     . $buzzwords[$cell] . "</td>";
    array_push($inAb,$buzzwords[$cell]);
        }
    else {
    $bingocard .= "<td>"
    . $buzzwords[$cell] . "</td>";  
    }

    if($rowend == 0 && $cell < 24) {
      $bingocard .= "</tr><tr>";
    }
  }

$bingocard .= "</tr>";
$bingocard .= "</tbody>";
$bingocard .= "</table>";
echo $bingocard;
}

bingo();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that number of `td`s which are children of `tr` is the **same** as number of `td`s with class `check` which are children of the same `tr`:

```
if ( $("tr").find("td").length == $("tr").find("td.check").length ) {
    $("tr").addClass( "check" );
}
```

Furthermore, use `each` to test every `tr` of your table `.tabell`:

```
$( ".tabell" ).find( "tr" ).each(function(idx) {
    var tr$ = $( this );
    if ( tr$.find("td").length == tr$.find("td.check").length ) {
        tr$.addClass( "check" );
    }
});
```

**Update**:
Because `tr` with `th` has no `td` (0) and no `td.check` (0 too), you should skip somehow first row. Maybe something like

```
$( ".tabell tbody" ).find( "tr" )`
```

or

```
0 < $("tr").find("td").length && $("tr").find("td").length == $("tr").find("td.check").length
```

Comment: This pretty much did it, thank you!
For some reason it added the class to my th too though, do you know why?

Comment: Excellent, very helpful!

Comment: You want to style the parent tr with class bingo when all cells have class check? Meaning if a tr has 8 cells then all 8 must have class check?

Answer (score 1):

White it easy:

```
$("tr").filter(function() { 
          return ! $(this).children("td").not(".check").length
        }).addClass("check")
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qf3v8m5h/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("table tr").each(function() {
  var rowCells = $(this).children("td");
  var rowLength = rowCells.length;
  var checkedCells = 0;
  $.each(rowCells,function(v) {
    if($(v).hasClass("check")) {
    checkedCells++;
    }
  });
  if(checkedCells==rowLength) {
  $(this).addClass('bingo');
  }
});
```